# Remove docker containers according to days filter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have containers with a specific tag. I want to delete all containers which are running more than 3 days.

```sh
docker ps -a | grep -i "ngnix" | xargs docker container prune --force --filter "until=3days"
```

But its not working. Can anyone please help me?

If it's not clear:
I have list of containers with same tag name but different container_name and now I want to first grep all the containers with same tag name and stop all containers running since last 3 days

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not clear but here is something I found related to it.

[docker container prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/) provides a filter to remove containers until a specific date:

```
docker container prune -a --filter "until=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' --date='-3 days')"
```

---

### OR

Using the command below, it will stop all containers running with a specific image, since the time of container id you provide (which is basically for time reference).

There are the following filters used :

`ancestor` - image_name

`status` - One of `created`, `restarting`, `running`, `removing`, `paused`, `exited`, or `dead`

`since` - The since filter shows only containers created since the container with given id or name.

( In your case give conaitner id which is just older than 3 days.)

```
docker container ls -a --filter ancestor=image_name --filter status=running --filter since=container_id | xargs docker stop
```

Using the above command will stop all containers running. Now in order to remove them, you just have to change filter values and change command to `docker rm`.

Comment: I have list of containers with same tag name but  different container_name and now I want to first grep all the containers with same tag name and prune/stop all containers running since last 3 days

Comment: By tag, you mean image used for running the container?

Comment: I have list of containers with different container_name and now I want to first grep all the containers with same name and stop all containers running since last 3 days. Now you are clear?

Comment: I have edited my answer, kindly check it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I think you are not getting my scenario. I already tried all these options.
My containers can be in running  status which I want to stop first which is running since last 3 days having similar container name. then after using stop I will prune it.

Comment: Before anyone tries this, please note that this deletes containers BEFORE the time not after.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me

Cleanup:
stage: cleanup
script:
- docker ps -a --filter "name=mapping" | grep 'days ago' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
- docker image prune -f --filter "until=48h"
- docker system prune -f